# How to unhide a layer with shortcut

Tags: shortcut, outliner, keymap

In the blender outliner, the shortcut <kbd>H</kbd> is used for hide a layer, but there isn't any shortcut for unhide a specific layer, only <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> for unhide all. I want to know why not just use <kbd>H</kbd> for toggle a layer? So that we can use <kbd>H</kbd> for hide and unhide a layer. It can be more convenient for all artist. Hope blender developer can see my advice and improve the function.

Comment: Alt+H Unhides the single active collection for me

Comment: Hello and welcome. This is Q&A site run by volunteers, we are not programmers nor in any way associated with the Blender Foundation, decision making nor development process of the software. For suggestions and feature requests use https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect or https://blenderartists.org. Before doing so consider that ideas are a dime-a-dozen, what we lack is manpower. Every single one of the millions of users have their own long list of personal wishes and desires, while comparatively very few people have the skills and knowledge to actually implement them.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Which version are you on? If I have let's say three collections and hide two with H, then Alt+H unhides both.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Indeed you are right it does unhide all.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thank you very very much for your advice and link, that's really help me. I'm a fresh bird in blender, please forgive my a dime-a-dozen idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default in Outliner keymap  <kbd>H</kbd> is mapped to *Outliner Hide* operator `outliner.hide`, but <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>H</kbd> is mapped to *Unhide All* with operator `outliner.unhide_all`.

By going to the outliner keymap at *Edit > Preferences > Keymap > Outliner* you can change the keymap of <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>H</kbd> to the command Show Collection with operator `outliner.collection_show`